# How to add battery status icon, current time and logo in Pyqt4 status bar

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm beginner, and I am learning OOP by example. I'm trying to make a simple app
with several widgets using pyqt4.

Is there a way to show battery icon, current time, and basic logo on every widget using pyqt4? Can I modify QStatusBar to do this?

EDIT:

My idea for ui is to have several widgets with different functionalities, all connected with QPushButton ( "Home", "Next", "Back" ), and I've done that, but I didn't find a way to show on every widget battery status, time and logo (similar like in Ubuntu's top right corner). App will be running on raspberry pi2, with TFT touch screen for RPI.

Comment: You could show your intent

Comment: read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html

Comment: Thanks for answering!